# infopath 2013 taking forever to publish to sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, publish, infopath

Good day,
I have a SharePoint 2013 list with over 16K list items. 
When the list was initially created, i had designed the form using Infopath 2013 and publishing the file was simple and fast (less than a minute)
As the data got bigger, the "Quick publish" started taking more and more time. 
Today as i made minor modifications to the form and tried to "Quick Publish" to the SharePoint list, it has been over 24 hours since the form is "Communicating with the SharePoint site".
I tried creating a template of the same list to to a new one that had no data, and published the same modified form which took less than a minute.
I have no idea what could be causing this and what is the solution
Note: I cannot use SharePoint designer 2013 due to IT Restrictions

Help Please :)

Comment: Anyone? I tried everything but no use.

Comment: I've tried quick publishing and left it for 24 hours...no success

Comment: does the list has calculated columns?